# Inappropriate stemming in nltk.stem

Tags: nltk

I was starting to learn stemming with nltk and a few words were quite inappropriately stemmed. 
For example:- very was stemmed to 'veri', important to 'import', once to 'onc', poorly to 'poorli' , etc.

I was just thinking that during data analysis, does it cause any error or these errors can be ignored?
Or is there a better option for the same purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The renown algorithm for stemming is [Porter stemming algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/porter/stemmer.html). Hence, you can use `stemmer = nltk.stemmer.PorterStemmer()` for the stemming. you can test it using `stemmer.stem('poorly')`.

Moreover, you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663617/3768871) for more details.